# Select new list of subquery in hql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, subquery, hql

I am trying to use the subquery in the attributes section. 
This works fine when the subquery returns only one result. Otherwise it shows an error.

> [2019-12-30 11:24:26] [21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
    @Query("select new com.example.rest.ShiftResponse(s.id, s.displayTitle, s.startTime, s.endTime, s.max, (select comm from ShiftGroup sg inner join sg.committee comm where sg.shift.id = s.id)) from Shift s where s.event.id = ?1")
```

Here's the constructor's signature

```
    public ShiftResponse(Long id, MultilangText displayTitle, LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime, Integer max, List<Committee> committees) {
```

Is there any way other than this to specify that I want that parameter to be a List?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this link ? [HQL new List(..) within new Object(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379238/hql-new-list-within-new-object)

It seems to me it was a similar question. Does it answer your question ?